# WMS GetFeatureInfo JSON error

Tags: javascript, openlayers, getfeatureinfo

I'm  trying to get informations from geoserver with AjaX jQuery of my spatial data at the clicked point using WMS GetFeatureInfo. 
But I have this ERROR :

> http://localhost:8082/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.3.0/exceptions_1_3_0.xsd">
>   
>         Invalid format 'text/javascript', supported formats are [text/plain, application/vnd.ogc.gml, text/xml,
>   application/vnd.ogc.gml/3.1.1, text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1, text/html,
>   application/json]

[image]

```
var clicked_coord;
var onSingleClick = function(evt){
    var coord = evt.coordinate;
    console.log(coord);
    var str = coord;
    var source1 = urldeep;
    var source2 = urlground;
    var layers_list = source1 + ',' + source2;
    var view = map.getView();
    var viewResolution = view.getResolution();
    url = groundwatertable.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
        evt.coordinate, viewResolution,view.getProjection(),
        {
            'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
            'FEATURE_COUNT': 20,
            'LAYERS': layers_list,
            'QUERY_LAYERS': layers_list
        });
    console.log(url);
    if (url) { //call parseResponse(data)
        clicked_coord = coord;
        $.ajax(url,
            {dataType: 'jsonp'}
        ).done(function (data) {
            });
    }
```

Comment: Presumably your code specifies `'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/javascript'`?  If you want a json response you should use `'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json'`

Comment: always the same error

Comment: Without seeing your code all help will be just guessing.

Comment: I just put it now

Comment: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?bbox=-130,24,-66,50&styles=population&format=jpeg&request=GetFeatureInfo&layers=topp:states&query_layers=topp:states&width=550&height=250&x=170&y=160&info_format=application/json works for me

Comment: I need to activate jsonp in config of geoserver